# Is Contrarian a Psychology Problem?

Tags: social-psychology

I was searching Google for a name given to a person who disagrees with the majority decision regardless whether he/she truly believe in the opposing idea.

An example, if everyone in group A agrees that John is showing attraction to Julie, Jim [Contrarian] will disagree and will say is something else. Now the same scenario, but group B, if everyone agrees that John is NOT showing attraction to Julie, Jim [Contrarian] will disagree and will say something else.

If Contrarian is the right word for Jim's behavior, is it a psychological problem? If yes, what is the closest term used in psychology to describe such behavior?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago a contrarian (a concept more usually found in literary or journalistic circles), in psychology would be called 'contra suggestive' or 'contra suggestible'. The two are, however, subtly different.  A contra suggestible person simply believes or does the opposite of something suggested by someone else.

Being a contrarian on the other hand usually involves going against cherished societal beliefs, or against prevailing group norms, and can be related to iconoclasm.

Contra-suggestibility (sometimes hyphenated) came out of the psychoanalitic literature, with all the fun and games that entails.

Comment: Very interesting! contra suggestible is very close to what I was looking for! The person creates an opposing idea and will *truly* believe in it without having any evidence.